# How to condition this a WP Custom field if exist

Tags: wordpress

In some Wordpress Posts I want to show the featured thumbnail image shown:

`fearless_post_thumbnail(); //located in content.php of template`

But in some posts I want to hide that thumbnail, In that case I would like to create a custom

> field (hide_thumb = 1 )

in posts where I want to hide it:

Question: Which condition should I wrap around:

```
fearless_post_thumbnail(); // it shows thumbnail.
```

Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your question and do better formatting.

Answer (score 0):

not sure I understand your question, but it sounds like you want to do this:

```
if ( $hide_thumb != 1 ) {
    fearless_post_thumbnail(); 
}
```

If your custom field, $hide_thumb, is set to TRUE or 1, then your thumbnail function will not execute.

Comment: This is exact what I want. I tested but $hide_thumb is returning empty. The value I gave(1) in the post custom filed is not being passed to post page. Any idea why?

Comment: Yes, you are right, that is what I want. But the for some reason the custome field value is not being passed to the page. I tried this suggestion from @adam:

`$custom_fields = get_post_custom();`

`$hide_thumb = $custom_fields['hide_thumb'];`

`if ( $hide_thumb != 1) {`

`    fearless_post_thumbnail();`

`}`

But the result is $hide_thumb = Array

Comment: ok, find out the contents of the `$hide_thumb` array by going `print_r($hide_thumb)`. It will show you a list of the keys and values it contains. Then you access the value you want like this: `if ( $hide_thumb[ 'key' ] != 1 )...`. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

The other answer here assumed you had already retrieved the value of of your custom field.  As per http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom,

```
$custom_fields = get_post_custom();
$hide_thumb = $custom_fields['hide_thumb'];
if ( $hide_thumb[0] != 1) {
    fearless_post_thumbnail();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Adam but still no value passed. I tried this solution and I echo $hide_thumb and result was $hide_thumb = Array

Comment: The only problem I have is that I can not retrieved the value of of my custom field.

Comment: Are you using this code within 'the loop' or are you writing your own loop? If so, you will need to pass the ID of the post to the get_post_custom() method

Comment: The wordpress codex indicates basically that $hide_thumb is always an array, even if expecting a single value. I'll edit my answer to hopefully address this. (The code edit will assume you have a single value)